# Programación Funcional en Python

Tags: python

****Problema:****

1. Aplicar impuesto**

Al trabajar en el equipo de desarrollo de una aplicación para el registro de las ventas de un supermercado, se identificó que el programa no aplica correctamente el impuesto al valor agregado (IVA, con un valor de 19%) de cada uno de los registros.

El listado de ventas está representado mediante una **lista de tuplas**, donde cada tupla tiene el **`nombre`** del producto en la primera posición y el **`precio`** (sin IVA) en la segunda posición.

```py
# Ejemplo de registros.
[
  ('Altavoces': 30000),
  ('Borrador': 1000),
  ('Cereal': 15000)
]
```

En este primer punto deberá implementar la función **`aplicar_impuesto`**, que recibe un registro y lo retorna con el impuesto aplicado. Es decir, la función recibirá una tupla de tamaño 2 con un nombre y un precio, y retornará otra tupla nueva, con el mismo nombre y con el precio tras aplicar el impuesto del 19%.

> **Nota:** este ejercicio puede ser solucionado mediante la definición de la función con la **`def`** o en una expresión con la sentencia **`lambda`**. Sin importar cual sea el caso, usted deberá crear una función con el nombre **`aplicar_impuesto`**. Tenga en cuenta los siguientes dos escenarios:

```py
# Opción 1 - Definición de función.
def aplicar_impuesto(registro):
  # ...
  return ...

# Opción 2 - Expresión lambda.
aplicar_impuesto = lambda ...
```

###**Entrada**

- **`producto`**: tupla de 2 elementos que contiene una cadena de texto (**`str`**) con el nombre del producto en la primera posición y un número real positivo (**`float`**) con el precio del producto sin IVA.

###**Salida**

- **`producto_con_iva`**: tupla de 2 elementos que contiene una cadena de texto (**`str`**) con el nombre del producto en la primera posición y un número real positivo (**`float`**) con el precio del producto con IVA del 19%.

**Codigo**

```py
def aplicar_impuesto(registros):
  for valor in registros:
    producto, precio = valor
    precio= float(precio)*1.19
    
    return(producto,precio)

registros = [("Producto A", 20.5), 
             ("Producto B", 92.3), 
             ("Producto C", 1000)]

for producto, precio in map(aplicar_impuesto, registros):
  print(f"{producto}: {precio:10.4f}")
```

**salida esperada**

```
Producto A:    24.3950
Producto B:   109.8370
Producto C:  1190.0000
```

Pregunta:  al hacer una función que desempaquete cada tupla en registro y la convierta en una nueva tupla donde el precio tenga el iva, puedo notar dentro del map que no itera la lista de registros, si no que manda a la función la lista completa, por lo anterior me toca hacer un for dentro de la función que si itere la lista que recibe y me retorne la nueva tupla deseada, sin embargo cuando entra en el for precio, producto, me sale un error de que el objeto tupla no es invocable, lo cual no me deja avanzar.

muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo que recibe tu función `aplicar_impuesto` es una tupla (solo una), pero al momento de usar el `for` estas recorriendo el contenido de la tupla. Simplemente basta con que tu función haga `return (registros[0], registros[1]*1.19)` y listo

Comment: Una nota respecto al título. La pregunta no va de programación funcional. Organizar el código en funciones no es programación funcional, sino _procedural_. La programación funcional es otra cosa (básicamente funciones que usan otras funciones como parámetros o como resultados, aunque esto es una simplificación)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Del código deducimos que `aplicar_impuesto` recibe una lista de artículos, y por tanto, debe retornar otra lista con los impuestos calculados.

```
def aplicar_impuesto(registros):
    nuevo_registro = []
    for producto, precio in registros:
        nuevo_registro.append((producto, float(precio) * 1.19))

    return nuevo_registro
```

En esta función primero creo una lista vacía y luego recorro los registros. Nota que puedo desempacar de inmediato cada tupla en el mismo `for`, obteniendo directamente precio y producto.

Con dichos valores creo una nueva tupla y la agrego a la nueva lista. Al terminar el recorrido, devuelvo esa lista.

El listado se simplifica:

```
for producto, precio in aplicar_impuesto(registros):
    print(f"{producto}: {precio:10.4f}")
```

No necesita aplicar `map`, pues la función recibe una lista de tuplas y devuelve la lista actualizada. Igualmente, en el mismo `for` desempaco precio y producto para imprimirlo.

#### Demo

```
def aplicar_impuesto(registros):
    nuevo_registro = []
    for producto, precio in registros:
        nuevo_registro.append((producto, float(precio) * 1.19))

    return nuevo_registro


registros = [("Producto A", 20.5),
             ("Producto B", 92.3),
             ("Producto C", 1000)]


for producto, precio in aplicar_impuesto(registros):
    print(f"{producto}: {precio:10.4f}")
```

produce:

```
Producto A:    24.3950
Producto B:   109.8370
Producto C:  1190.0000

Process finished with exit code 0
```